# Условие в условии Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

[image: Таблица Excel]

У меня есть таблица, мне нужно сделать два условия. Если A2 имеет значения "Частник" и с E2 выбрана "E4", тогда значения F2 умножается на 47. Но если в E2 выбрана значение "95", A2 остается такое же условие, тоже "Частник", тогда F2 умножается на 45. и вот подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Пока пытался понять, как это сделать написал такую формулу:

=ЕСЛИ(И(A2="Частник";E2="E4");F2*47;ЕСЛИ(И(A2="Частник";E2="95");F2*45;0))

Работает почти правильно, за исключением, что когда я выбираю 95 он выдаёт 0.

Comment: "значения F2 умножается на 47" - это F2*47, а не F247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=ЕСЛИ(И(A2="Частник";E2="E4");F247;ЕСЛИ(И(A2="Частник";E2=**95**);F245;0))

Число 95 это не то же самое, что строка "95".

Comment: @АлексейР Я обратил на это внимание, но оставил на усмотрение ОР, так как вопрос не про это.

Answer (score 0):

На выбор :)

Стандартно:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2="Частник";F2*ЕСЛИ(E2="E4";47;ЕСЛИ(E2=95;45;));)
```

Побаловаться :)

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2="Частник";F2*ВПР(E2;{0;0:95;45:"E4";47};2;);)
=ЕСЛИ(A2="Частник";F2*СУММ((E2={"E4";95})*{47;45});)
```

Без функций листа:

```
=F2*(A2="Частник")*(45*(E2<>"")+2*(E2="E4"))
```